# Using chdir() to change directory from Terminal

Tags: c, shell, chdir

I am using `chdir()` to change directory to the value passed as an argument to this function.

I understand that when I run my C program using `gcc myCd.c` and `./a.out ..` this changes the directory to the parent directory "within" the C program (i.e. a child process is spawned for the a.out process, and the change of directory happens within that child process).

What I want to do is, change the directory at the terminal using this C program. I tried writing a shell script for the same, and then sourcing it, and running, that works, but I wanted to achieve this using C.

Comment: can you explain what is sourcing the script?

Comment: at the terminal entering 'source scriptname'  very similar '. scriptname'  Note: 'source' is not available in every scripting language.  Usually it can be found in csh and bash

Comment: @Anton.P, by sourcing the script I meant, running the script in one of the two ways:
1. `. myScript.sh`
2. `source myScript.sh`

But as @user3629249 has pointed out, it is not available in every scripting language. So will have to think of yet another way out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are attempting to do can't be done.  The *current working directory* is a per-process attribute.

If you run a program which changes its *cwd*, it does not affect any other processes, except for any children it might create after the `chdir()`.

The correct way to change the terminal's working directory is to use the `cd` command which the shell executes on your behalf and remains within the same process.  That is, `cd` is one of several commands that the shell does not `fork()`; this makes the `cd` command work as expected.

`source`ing a shell file makes it run within the shell's process.  However, if you were to run the script without `source`, you'd find there was the exact same problem as with a C program:  the shell forks to create a process for the script to run, it runs and then exits, and then the shell continues, but without its cwd changed.

Answer (score 1):

this is the way to change the current working directory in C

this needs the `unistd.h` header file to be included

```
if( 0 != chdir( "pathToNewDirectory" ) )
{ // then chdir failed
    perror( "chdir failed" );
   // handle error
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the same way I have written my C program. And as mentioned in the comments and answers referenced to this post, the C Program will be spawned as a separate process, and will not change the directory of the parent process (the terminal)